# Rectangle used in ZXING Library for scanning QR code is not centerd

Tags: java, android, zxing

I have requirement in  which I need to scan the QR code using ZXING library in Android application.
I have added complete ZXING code in my project and written following code for opening camera for QR code scanning.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
    intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

the rectangle used to scan QR code on camera isn't at center? rectangle is coming at bottom right corner.
I haven't changed any code from ZXING library.
Can anybody help me out for this solution to get that rectangle in Centered?

Comment: Can you pls provide the target and minimum sdk version of your application you are developing?

Comment: Minimum sdk version I am using for this application is 1.6. I am testing it on device Motorola Milestone which has Android version 2.0.

Comment: I have tested it on Samsung Galaxy S(android version 2.2) and getting same problem. I have installed separate zxing barcode scanner code and tested and surprisingly it works fine. the issue comes only when I integrate the zxing QR code scanner code in my application.

Comment: Actually I also faced one issue like this while integrating the zxing code with my application. At that time the Min SDK version I used was 3 and when I changed the SDK version to 4 I went correct.. Thats why I asked the min SDK version of your app. Kindly go through the following link, this might help you: http://www.falatic.com/index.php/12/building-zxing-for-android-part-3-using-eclipse

Comment: @krishna5688 in Which Layout is problem Land or port.What is your Activity Default Layout.Are you Using Zxing 1.7 android client.

Comment: @Herry Sorry for late reply, this problem is occurring in both Layouts. And yes I am using Zxing 1.7 android client.

Comment: @krishna5688 Have you give this android:layout_gravity="center" in <com.google.zxing.client.android.ViewfinderView , as you have said before you have not change as code in Zxing android,So also need to put android:screenOrientation="landscape" in your activity if you have not stay at one of land or port then for first time your rect for scan come in center but when you change device orientation may be rect will not come in center .

Answer (score 2):

PS, developer here, this was fixed (or rather, workaround) about a month ago in the source tree. A version 4.0 is going to be released shortly that contains the change. A beta version is here: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/downloads/list

The problem is that some devices think they are in landscape mode at creation, even when the app is landscape-only. It's a platform or device problem but easily worked around.